# CakePHP 3 Ajax security handling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Javascript function called when the user clicks on a button.  There are multiple "bookmark" buttons on the page:

```
javascript:ajax_bookmark_url(1,"http://www.legitsite.com");
```

How can i make this more secure?
I mean a user can just type the following in the chrome console;

```
javascript:ajax_bookmark_url(1,"http://www.notalegitsite.com");
```

The above function call is bad as the user can see the url being bookmarked? Do I need to encrypt it? Any advice would be great.

I assume I need add the security component from `CakePHP` 3? I'm not sure

JS function:

```
//bookmark an articles url
function ajax_bookmark_url(id,url){  

    var mydata=new Object();        

    mydata.feed_id=id;
    mydata.url=url; 

    jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: mydata,
    url: '<?= $this->request->webroot ?>feeds/bookmark',
    success: function(response,textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        //success
        alert(response); 
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) { 
        console.log(response);
    }
    });
}
```

`CakePHP` 3 controller function:

```
public function bookmark(){

    if ($this->request->is('ajax') && $this->request->is('post')) { 
        $myTable = TableRegistry::get('user-bookmarks');
        $userBookmark = $myTable->newEntity();      

        $userBookmark = $myTable->patchEntity($userBookmark, $this->request->data);

        //set the looged in user's id
        $userBookmark->user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');     

        //auto generated
        $userBookmark->created=Time::now();
        $userBookmark->modified=Time::now();

        $this->autoRender=false;

        try{
            if ($myTable->save($userBookmark)) {
                //success
                $status="Bookmark Saved."; 
            }
        }
        catch(\PDOException $e){
            //should log this error
            $status="error: DB Error, Bookmark already exists. ".$e;
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            //should log this error
            $status="error: General Exception";
        }

        $this->response->body(json_encode($status));
        return $this->response; 
    }
    else{
        $status['msg']="Non Ajax Request"; 
        $this->response->body(json_encode($status));
        return $this->response; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that makes a URL legit? Where do the URLs stem from?